# Spanning drives, managing partitions in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning

I have a Windows Vista machine with a 250GB hard drive currently split into four partitions (call them C:, I:, J:, and K:).  I've just put another spare 250GB drive into the machine.

I'd like to span the two drives (make a two drive JBOD array) that keeps the partition structure the same, but makes the space on the new drive part of the C: partition on the old drive.

The method I thought of was to backup all the partitions, format both drives, use the partitioning software on a Linux live CD to create a spanned volume, restore the C: partition to the spanned volume, shrink the partition, and then restore the other three partitions.

That's a big pain though - is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vista does not support a system partition that is spanned, unless you have a host controller that supports it.

Comment: Ok, scratch that idea.  Thank you for the tip.